# symfony3/php: retrieve attribute from url for api

Tags: php, api, symfony

For a datatable, I have to use a REST API.

My url is for example: 
http://localhost:8000/trial/1

In this page to make the api call I use the following:

`url: "rest->{{ path('erp_interventionapi_get') }}",`

I need to get the attribut id="1" to make the correct call(find by id in the database), but I don't know how to get it.

I've tried this

```
    /**
 * @Rest\Get("/api_i/get")
 */
public function getAction(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->attributes->get('id');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $trial = $em->find('ErpBundle:Trial', $id);
    return $em->getRepository('ErpBundle:Intervention')->findBy(array('trial' => $trial));
}
```

but I have this error message:

> The identifier id is missing for a query of ErpBundle\Entity\Trial

The following isn't working either:

```
    /**
 * @Rest\Get("/api_i/get")
 */
public function getAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $trial = $em->find('ErpBundle:Trial', $id);
    return $em->getRepository('ErpBundle:Intervention')->findBy(array('trial' => $trial));
}
```

I guess it is because it try to retrieve the id from the url /api_i/get and not from the webpage itself.

So is it possible to get the attribute from the url where I make the API call?

Excuse me if I make mistakes in my way to say things, I'm still pretty new to this :)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set id in path function:

```
{{ path('erp_interventionapi_get', {id: app.request.attributes.get('id')}) }}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is quite right. When the url is created, my assumption is it's not _necessarily_ on the same `$id`-related Trial url. What if it was a list of Trials? The id should come from what's passed into the template call, not (necessarily) what's in the URL when the path is created.

Comment: Thank you both for the qucik answers! I actually think this is the corrrect way to do it. As this is a page for one trial and I try to get a list of interventions related to this trial (so related to this trial id which is the id in the url). Weirdly though, It still give me the the error messages with both functions I showed above. If I look in the ajax request profiler, I do have a GET paramater with the id. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you're passing in the Trial object (either as a list or a single one), so when you use Symfony's Twig function `path()` (note, this is NOT a Twig function, it comes from the Twig bundle for Symfony), you need to pass in the id:

```
{{ path('erp_interventionapi_get', { id: trial.id }) }}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
{% for trial in trials %}
    {{ path('erp_interventionapi_get', { id: trial.id }) }}
{% endfor %}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#linking-to-pages

Note, if you're outputting this as JSON for a SPA or widget-based consumption, I would recommend doing that as a client-side router strategy, e.g., build the route on the client with serialized data (sans embedded URL). For instance, in Backbone you would tell it how to "get" to a resource like:

```
this.route("trial/:id", "trial", function(id){ ... });
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Comment: Thank you again, this is working as well, I didn't think of retrieving the id from the object but it correctly add a GET parameter in the ajax request. It still gives me the same error messages though and don't retrieve the id in the function. Regarding your note, I'm using webix, and just followed the documentation. Thanks again!

Comment: What REST bundle are you using for `@Rest\Get("/api_i/get")`? I would think it would be `@Rest\Get("/api_i/get/{id}")`, but that's [the Router component parameter syntax](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#adding-wildcard-requirements). The `get` thing is still weird to me as well, sure seems like it should be `@Rest\Get("/api_i/trial/{id}")` or `@Rest\Get("/api_i/intervention")`. The word "get" as an action would seemingly refer to the Http method GET and seem to indicate some type of front controller-ish action, which is sort've not RESTful at all.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now! I used get in the route in order to find it easily with debug:router. I didn't know I was doing something wrong, thanks for the highlighting this!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to finish the thought here: `@Rest\Get("/api_i/intervention/{i_id}/trial/{t_id}")`, then `interventionAction($i_id, $t_id) {...}`.

Comment: I actually have one more issue with the POST method. It is a datatable and I'm able to add a new row with the POST method. I'd like to be able to retrieve the trial id parameter (to fill in the database accordingly when I add a row in a trial page), like in the get method but I'm not able to do @Rest\Post("/api/intervention/{trialid}"), right? (No route found for "POST /api/intervention/1/" (from "http://localhost:8000/trial/1")

Comment: Start another question, it's unrelated to this one.